# Magento 2: Override a function from a Model with a plugin

Tags: magento2

I want to Override a function(public function getName) from a Model(Customer.php), Searched google, I created a plugin, but it wasn't display, Any wrong about this? Thanks

I want to override this as below:
(Original File: vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Customer.php)

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

to

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getLastname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

> 1：registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magecn_ChineseName',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2: etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magecn_ChineseName" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3: etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer">
        <plugin name="ChineseNameFieldsModel" type="Magecn\ChineseName\Plugin\Customer\Model\Customer"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4:Plugin/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magecn\ChineseName\Plugin\Customer\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as Subject;

class Customer extends Subject
{
    /**
     * Get full customer name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function beforeGetName(Subject $subject, $name)
    {
        $name = '';

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getLastname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to override this method using plugin, use afterGetName method....beforeGetName method will override only params

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you cannot use after, before plugin.

Use below method in you plugin

> Plugin/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magecn\ChineseName\Plugin\Customer\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer as Subject;

class Customer extends Subject
{
    /**
     * Get full customer name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetName(Subject $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        //$result = $proceed();
        $name = '';

        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getLastname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .= ' ' . $this->getFirstname();
        if ($this->_config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
}
```